# MySQL Telnet Connection Timeout Issue Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: mysql, timeout, telnet, ubuntu-20.04, connection-timeout

I am trying to establish a `telnet` connection to a MySQL server running at Ubuntu server(through SHH) `127.0.0.1 on port 3306`. However, I encounter the following output:

`Trying 127.0.0.1... Connected to 127.0.0.1. Escape character is '^]'. [ 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 2%0d|yj}?tPWSG^caching_sha2_password2#08S01Got timeout reading communication packetsConnection closed by foreign host.`

The connection seems to be established, but I receive a "Got timeout reading communication packets" error, and the connection is closed. I'm using MySQL 8.0.34 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: That's what I'd expect to see - you're connecting to the MySQL server's port and the MySQL server is attempting to negotiate with what it thinks is a connection attempt from a MySQL client.  However, telnet isn't a MySQL client, so the connection attempt fails.

Comment: I can connect to mysql successfully with this command. `mysql -u user -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306`

Comment: Indeed.  That's the command-line MySQL client, which is successfully negotiating with the MySQL server on that host and port.  As mentioned above, `telnet` is not a MySQL client.

Comment: Actually, I'm a newbie in the server setup field. So I can connect to mysql through SSH, with port=3306 and different, IPs like(ec2-instance-ip). But when I try with this through the browser with HTTP and HTTPS (ec2-instance-ip). it returns the error (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query)

Comment: When you say 'I can connect to mysql through SSH' what do you mean?  Are you establishing an SSH tunnel?  Also, when you're connecting 'through the browser' what do you mean - some kind of script (Rails? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490679/mysql2errorconnectionerror-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock)

Comment: I'm going to set up a server for Ruby on Rails. So I can connect the ubuntu(ec2 instance) through this command(ssh -i ~/Downloads/new-server.pem ubuntu@x.xx.xxx.xx). After SSH I can establish a connection to mysql and can do everything.
through the browser, which means trying to access my application(website) through ec2-instance-ip

Comment: So are your webserver and your MySQL server the same machine, or different?  If they are both on the same host, then your Rails config should be straightforward (no need for an SSH tunnel), although take note that when it comes to granting access, MySQL handles '127.0.0.1' and 'localhost' distinctly

Comment: Please if you have some time, here are my main issue details.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77306344/aws-ec2-instance-unable-to-connect-from-browser-but-mysql-access-via-ssh-works